# Characterization of Jordan Bases with Jordan Chains

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, change-of-basis

A theorem in some notes I'm reading states:

Let $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ be linear and $E = (e_1,\dots,e_n)$ be a basis for V. Then E is a Jordan Basis for T and V if and only if there exists $k \geq 1$ and integers $i(0),\dots,i(k)$ such that $0 = i(0) < \dots < i(k) = n$ and

$(e_{i(t)+1},e_{i(t)+2}, \dots, e_{i(t+1)})$

Is a Jordan chain for all t with $0 \leq t < k$.

The conditions stated make no sense to me (it is probably a mistake in the notes), so what I'm looking for is an explanation of the last part of the theorem, or an exact statement of what it should be. Thanks

Comment: If it helps, in lectures he skipped this proposition saying that it was unnecessary. I don't really see how it follows from definitions $16, 22, 24$, so perhaps emailing him would clear it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result (which is more of a definition) is that E is a Jordan basis if and only if it is a basis which is a union of disjoint Jordan chains.